# How can I evaluate this contour complex integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Question:
$$\oint_{c}^{} \frac{e^{{z}^{2}}}{z-2}dz$$

And the contour is this figure: [image: Contour C1]

Now it would have been great if they had defined the contour but no such luck. The only hint is that I can assume lines connecting inner and outer circular paths are coincident.

Here is my attempt:

Let $C_A$ be the inner circle and let $C_B$ be the outer ellipse.
And let $C_D$ be the line connecting the two circles going down then the line going up must be $-C_D$.

Hence, let $C_1=C_D \cup -C_A \cup -C_D \cup C_B $ since positive orientation is counter clockwise!

Since $C_1$ is closed  and $f(z)$ is analytic inside $C_1$ the by Cauchy-Goursat Theorem

$\oint_{C_D \cup -C_A \cup -C_D \cup C_B }^{} f(z)dz=0$

Expand the integral:

$\int_{C_D }^{} f(z)dz - \int_{C_A}^{} f(z)dz - \int_{C_D}^{} f(z)dz + \int_{C_B}^{} f(z)dz = 0$

1st and third integrals cancel which leaves us with:

$\int_{C_A}^{} f(z)dz=\int_{C_B}^{} f(z)dz$

Now what should I take as $f(z)$?

Can it be like this where I also use the Little Integral Theorem with the above corollary of the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem?

$\oint_{c}\frac {f(z)}{z-2}dz$ and since $n=-1$ ($n$ being the power) then:

$\oint_{c}\frac {f(z)}{z-2}dz = 2\pi i \cdot f(z)= 2\pi i \cdot e^4$

Can anyone help me clear my doubts about this? Any help at all would be most appreciated!

Comment: The arrows on your contour suggest your contour crosses itself. Is that correct?

Comment: On your diagram, you do both circles in the clockwise direction, correct?  (That's what makes the curve cross itself.)  That seems an unusual choice.  But if that is correct, then see that it has winding number  $-2$ about the point $2$.

Comment: @GEdgar I am sorry I have no idea what a winding number is. Also this question is part of a HW and not a diagram of my own...

Comment: @degenerate_matter I believe it helps me prove using the path deformation corollary of the C-G theorem that the integrals for the two circles/ellipses are equal so yes I guess the contour crosses itself.

Comment: As you state the integrals around the two circular contours are equal (upto a possible sign). If the circles are traversed in opposite directions then the contributions cancel giving you a total path integral of zero. This can also be seen, because in this case the pole does not lie within the integration contour and so the residue theorem tells you that the integral is zero. Alternatively if they are traversed in the same direction then the result is twice that from a single circular contour - which you can find from the residue theorem.

Comment: Professor said the residue theorem is at the end of the semester so 2 weeks from now. Is there another way to solve it without residue theorem?

Comment: Your path can be homotopically deformed to a null path in $\Bbb C\setminus\{2\}$, here is how to think about the deformation. At the beginning we have a long path as follows. Start at the "north pole", N for short, of the path, then go around on the big circle, hitting E, S, W, and N again. Then go down, we are on the smaller circle, move on it to W, S, E, N, and go up. This route is to long for me, so i will cheat, the first day i will start on the big circle at NE, then on the big circle going E, S, W, and stop at NW. Instead of going down, we go to the center $2$ till we reach the small cir

Comment: ... circle, then move on it NW, W, S, E, NE, then go radially back on the big center. In this way, the small, thin cut / wedge in N becomes wider. And we make it wider and wider, till it disappears.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's Integral Formula?

Comment: That is the very next thing I am supposed to study in the next lecture.

Comment: @MarkS. Should I put off doing this question until then?

Comment: If the directions of the loops aren't a mistake (yours or theirs), then this would be a bit hard to do without that. I would recheck the directions and then ask the instructor if they're correct if it still seems like the loops go the same way when you recheck.

Comment: @MarkS. I learned the Cauchy Integral Formula today and I showed my professor this question. She said that this question cannot be solved by Cauchy Integral Formula: $$\oint_{C} \frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz=2\pi i \cdot f(a) $$ since $a=2$ is not inside the contour. She said if it was singular loop then you could apply CIF but not in this case because of $C_D$